# How to encrypt field in MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I need to encrypt one field in a mongo document.
What is the best way to do it?
I use spring. 
There is spring annotation for it?

Comment: Not yet supported but there's an open JIRA ticket for this: [**Add support to selectively encrypt document fields**](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-874).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the encryption can be done for now only from java.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936242/encrypt-password-fields-in-mongodb) you have the same question asked last month

this has been done already in ruby, so if you want to use jruby for this in your project take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936242/encrypt-password-fields-in-mongodb)

or you can wait until the MongoDB includes this in their API

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library that adds support for @Encrypted annotation fields:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.bol</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb-encrypt</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

To configure spring:

```
@Bean
public CryptVault cryptVault() {
    return new CryptVault()
            .with256BitAesCbcPkcs5PaddingAnd128BitSaltKey(0, oldKey)
            .with256BitAesCbcPkcs5PaddingAnd128BitSaltKey(1, secretKey)
            // can be omitted if it's the highest version
            .withDefaultKeyVersion(1);
}

@Bean
public EncryptionEventListener encryptionEventListener(CryptVault cryptVault) {
    return new EncryptionEventListener(cryptVault);
}
```

And to use it:

```
@Document
public class MyBean {
    @Id
    public String id;

    // not encrypted
    @Field
    public String nonSensitiveData;

    // encrypted primitive types
    @Field
    @Encrypted
    public String secretString;

    @Field
    @Encrypted
    public Long secretLong;

    // encrypted sub-document (MySubBean is serialized, encrypted and stored as byte[])
    @Field
    @Encrypted
    public MySubBean secretSubBean;

    // encrypted collection (list is serialized, encrypted and stored as byte[])
    @Field
    @Encrypted
    public List<String> secretStringList;

    // values containing @Encrypted fields are encrypted
    @Field
    public MySubBean nonSensitiveSubBean;

    // values containing @Encrypted fields are encrypted
    @Field
    public List<MySubBean> nonSensitiveSubBeanList;

    // encrypted map (values containing @Encrypted fields are replaced by encrypted byte[])
    @Field
    public Map<String, MySubBean> publicMapWithSecretParts;
}

public class MySubBean {
    @Field
    public String nonSensitiveData;

    @Field
    @Encrypted
    public String secretString;
}
```

For more info, check out [the project website](https://github.com/bolcom/spring-data-mongodb-encrypt)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17766399)

Comment: there is nothing more to add. it's a library that _is_ the answer to the question. please don't misuse moderator right.

Comment: No, an actual answer would show how the library can be used in the answer itself. See also [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: You know that's just copying the doc from the project website, which is doomed to get outdated, but there you go.

Comment: Thanks. Of course it is entirely possible that the linked documentation changes (or maybe even disappears), and that is exactly the reason why an answer should stand on its own, and not rely on links except for supporting information.

Comment: right, but outdated info is maybe worse than no info. you can (and should) always google for the most relevant info, but the question here was more about keywords than copied doc.

Comment: If you want to discuss established rules and expectations for answers, you are welcome to start a discussion on [meta]

Comment: I just wanted to put the library I made when I was googling for the same question, to the same places I've been looking at back then. I had no idea it's so hard to post a helpful answer around here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use custom encryption scheme and store that, into database. In rails it will be easy to do so.

```
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :encrypted_me, type: String, encrypted: true
```

If you can describe what platform you are using that will make some clarification.