# How to encrypt Spring Boot application data in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, encryption

I have a Spring Boot application that stores payment information in the database. The application has end-points

- `GET /api/orders` - get orders by filter
- `POST /api/orders` - add a new order
- `PUT /api/orders` - update order
- `DELETE /api/orders` - delete order

These endpoints are not secure itself, and I do not want to secure them on the application level. All traffic from the user goes to HTTPS proxy, which will decrypt it and forward to the application.

However, I use mongo atlas free version for prototyping
https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/faq

All the data I put into the database must be encrypted. Even the document structure (fields names and types) must be encrypted.

[How to encrypt a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726414/how-to-encrypt-field-in-mongodb) does not work for me, because I want to encrypt the whole document.
I do not want to use unofficial libraries like bellow (thus no one guarantees if the library is secure)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.bol</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb-encrypt</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

One idea that came to me is to configure the application to use a password (somehow configured or generated at given moment of time).

```
/**
* Provides a password to encrypt a document.
**/
// TODO  How to do it better? I still have to improve it.
@Component
public class PasswordProviderImpl implements PasswordProvider {
    
    private static final byte[] MASTER_PASSWORD = {1, 11, 37, 166, 11, 77};

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    // I do not care about the implementation yet
    public char [] getPassword() {
        final byte[] envPassword = environment.getProperty("appplicationPassword").toString().toByteArray();
        return envPassword;
    }
}
```

```
/**
* Encrypts input byte array with provided password, afterwards, cleans input data and password - populates them with zeros - 0.
**/
@Component
public class Encryptor {
    private PasswordProvider passwordProvider;

    public byte [] encrypt(final byte unecrypted) {
        final byte [] password = passwordProvider.getPassword();
        final byte [] encrypted = xor(unecrypted, password);
        makeZeros(password);
        makeZeros(unecrypted);
        return encrypted;
    }
    
    private void makeZeros(final byte[] array) { /*Implementation*/}
    private byte[] xor(final byte [] arg1, final byte[] arg2) {/*Implementation*/}
}
```

```
/**
* Represents a unit of data in my application. Its values and fields and structure - everything should be encrypted.
**/
public class Order {
    private ObjectId id;
    private Instant createdDate;
    private Instant updatedDate;
    private Money amount;
    private String additionalDetails;

    // gettters, setters, constructor
}
```

Converter, found [Set MongoDb converter programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780692/set-mongodb-converter-programmatically)

```
/**
* It is declared application configuration. It defines how to store {@link Order} in mongodb
**/
@Component
public OrderConverter implements onverter<Order, SecuredOrder> {
    
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private Encryptor encryptor;
    private Base64Converter base64Converter;

    @Override 
    public SecuredOrder convert(Order source) { 
        final String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(source);
        final unencrypted = json.toByteArray();
        final byte[] encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(unencrypted);
        final String payload = base64Converter.toBase64(encrypted);
        return SecuredOrder.of(order.getId(), payload);
    }
}
```

```
public class SecuredOrder {
    private ObjectId id; // same as in order id
    private String encryptedPayload; // The converter will make it
}

@Service
public OrderService {
    public void saveOrder(Order order) {
        orderRepository.save(order);
    }
}
```

If you have done a similar thing, please give me a direction. I would really like to do it properly.

Also, mongodb provides encryption mechanism, so maybe I should use it?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/#encrypted-storage-engine

Comment: You say 'thus no one guarantees if the library is secure', but then copy random code snippets from the internet... BTW the spring-data-mongodb-encrypt library does exactly what you want, you just put your data in a sub-document and mark the field with @Encrypted, but up to you if you prefer homecooked solutions to opensource ones.

Comment: OK, I was confused with the library group id bol (I had not know that company before). How did I know who will mainaint the library? I see it a company that open sourced some their solutions. And the company is known and will care about their reputation.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to use the WiredTiger storage engine and you are using MongoDB 3.2 or above, you can utilize it's [Encryption at Rest](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/) capability (as you mentioned at the bottom of your post!), but be advised this is available for the enterprise version only.